# Arbitrary Keyword Arguments: Why do we write "=" between the keys and the values in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading the book Python Crash Course, and in the following I have a confusion why a dictionary is defined as `user_info={k=v,k1=v1,...}` and not `user_info={k:v,k1:v1,...}`. Here is the code from the book (slightly altered for name of person):

```
def build_profile(first, last, **user_info):
    profile = {}
    profile['first_name'] = first.title()
    profile['last_name'] = last.title()
    for key, value in user_info.items():
        profile[key] = value
    return profile
build_profile('freddie','mercury',location='uk',field='rock')
```

In the book, he says the following: The
double asterisks before the parameter `**user_info` cause Python to create
an empty dictionary called `user_info` and pack whatever name-value pairs it
receives into this dictionary.

Now, when I  type in the values for the dictionary the ordinary way (ie key:value),
python gives me an error.

Could somebody explain why is this so?

Comment: There is no `user_info={k=v,k1=v1,...}` in the code. This is a difference in syntax between keyword arguments (`=`), and literal construction of a dictionary (`:`). The former just also happens to produce a dictionary, but it's through a difference mechanism.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  I don't understand the "The former just also happens to produce a dictionary, but it's through a difference mechanism." part. Could you please elaborate if possible?

Comment: It means that `location='uk'` and `field='rock'` are available as a dictionary within the function. You can test it by adding `print(user_info)` in the function. The author may have been a little sloppy in mixing 'normal' language with 'syntax'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are objects with key-value pairs. There's a special literal for creating dicts:

```
{'key': 'value'}
```

You could also use the `dict` constructor to do the same thing:

```
dict(key='value')
```

What's shown here are *named function arguments.* Taking a step back…

These are function definitions:

```
def foo(bar, baz): ...
```

This function defines two parameters. You can give these parameters default values:

```
def foo(bar, baz=42): ...
```

The parameter `baz` has the default value 42. When calling the function, you can supply the arguments *positionally*:

```
foo('a', 14)
```

Or, and here we go, you can supply the arguments *by name*:

```
foo(bar='a', baz=14)
foo(baz=14, bar='a')  # exactly the same as above
```

This is in fact what the `dict` constructor does, it's a function call with named arguments.

Now, you can also accept arbitrary named arguments in your function:

```
def foo(**kwargs): ...
```

Any named argument you pass in will be accepted and land in the `kwargs` parameter, which happens to be a dict (because that's the natural data structure for a key-value mapping).

So, you're not constructing a dict with `=` there. You're calling a function that accepts arbitrary named arguments via `**`, and those end up being a dict. Function parameters or arguments always involve the `=` syntax. The only time `:` is used is in *dict literals*.

Comment: would it be correct to say that the ```**``` thing is the same like the ```dict``` function? as in ```**key=value``` is equivalent to ```dict(key=value)```?

Comment: No. Don't conflate these. `**` is for packing named arguments, which happens to end up being a dict. It's also for *unpacking* mappings (which can be things other than a dict) into named arguments (i.e. `foo(**args)` when *calling* a function).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to think of this might be that you are allowing the user to input in as many values as they would want. Say you have a function like this:

```
def Function(*arguments):
    ...
```

Here, the asterisks before the arguments means that the user is allowed to supply as many values as they want into the parameter. It it thus creating a list of values. Similarly, adding two asterisks before also means that the user is allowed to type in as many values as they want, but this time, the values will be organized as a dictionary.

so I have a function:

```
def Function(**arguments):
    print(arguments)
```

then, if I call it like so:

```py
Function("Key0", 0, "Key1", 1, ...)
```

The function takes the even values (value 0, 2, ...) as the keys and the odd values (1, 3, ...) as the values. So this code would print:

```
{"Key0": 0, "Key1": 1, ...}
```

Now note, this is not exactly how it functions at the lower lever, but it is a good way to think about it.

Comment: That even/odd thing… is just not how `**kwargs` work at all.

Comment: Well yea, but it's helpful to think about it that way to not get confused. It takes every other argument to be the key, and the one after that to be the values

Comment: Since named arguments are *a thing*, and quite an important thing, in Python, I don't think it's terribly helpful using these weird analogies.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps